# Weird Passwords... field pops up in big sur

Tags: passwords, gui, macos-bigsur

i don't know if this is a right place to ask, but Im having hard time figuring out why a passwords... button pops up randomly on my big sur OS on the left side of the screen. Clicking it doesn't to anything and I cant get rid of it and gets pretty annoying. I'm attaching a screenshot…

[image]

Does anyone have any idea, why this button pops up and how the get rid of it?

Comment: That's the button you get on a web page where either there is no existing form information, or there are conflicting versions. I have no clue why it would pop up in Finder though.

Comment: It pops up randomly. Im using chrome and even after killing it this things stays there. It just comes and goes randomly but can be really annoying as it overlaps other applications too

Comment: I never saw that window on mine....Do you have a 3rd party password app? Have you checked in activity monitor for processes and tried to figure out what process this window belongs to?

Comment: I only use keychain. Killing it wont get rid of the pop-up

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figured it out.

Forticlient which is use to connect to a VPN was causing this issue. Killing the process removed the pop-up too

Comment: thank you. that pop-up made me crazy. Forticlient seems to be pretty buggy, I've had it lock my keyboard several times, too (when a connection fails, which happens relatively often).

Comment: Killed all forti-stuff but the popup is still appearing.

Comment: shutting down forticlient worked for me.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue since upgrading to macOS 11 Big Sur, but did not have FortiClient installed. It turned out to be caused by an old version of Mobile Mouse Server. They fixed it in version 3.5.4.

Comment: No "Mobile Mouse Server" here. Still popping up...